# Can I send output from a Windows child process to the parent?

Tags: windows, winapi

Other than creating pipes for standard in/out/error, is there any easy way in Win32 API to redirect those handles to the parent process? If the child process has a console window, the output/error seems to go to it, rather than the parent's console window, even when the handles are inherited. What I'd really like is for a windowless child process to send its out/error to the parent's console (easily?). Advice appreciated.

Comment: You can't redirect a process's STD(IN|OUT|ERR) after the process is running. Redirection is handled at process creation, so the parent would have to provide alternative STD(IN|OUT|ERR) handles when creating the child process. But, there are plenty of other ways for processes to exchange data with each other without relying on STD(IN|OUT|ERR) at all - named pipes, mailslots, sockets, shared memory/files, window messages, ActiveX/COM, RPC, just to name a few.  Use whatever you want to have the child send data to the parent, and then the parent can display the data in its own window as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to **display** the `stdout` and `stderr` of your child process to the console of the parent process, you can use [`AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) in the child process to attach it to the console of the parent process. Or In parent, specify `dwCreationFlags` of `CreateProcess` as 0, according to the [Creation of a Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console):

> By default, a console process inherits its parent's console.

(there is no guarantee that input is received by the process for which it was intended. Make sure you don' t need to use the stdin for child process)

However, this method cannot interact with the parent process. If the parent process needs to obtain these output data, it still needs to use Interprocess Communications to send the data to the parent process.

This method allows the child process and the parent process to use the same console, but the parent process cannot directly obtain the output data of the child process. If the parent process needs to get the data, it still needs to use [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) to send the data to the parent process.

EDIT:

Here is the sample

child:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(VOID)
{
    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    int i = 5;
    while (i--)
    {
        printf("printf\n");
        std::cout << "child " << i << std::endl;
        fflush(stdout);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

parent:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    WCHAR cmd[] = L"Path\\child.exe";
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES se = {};
    se.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    se.bInheritHandle = true;
    se.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, &se, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    BOOL ret = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hFile);
    printf("parent1\n");
    ret = CreateProcessW(cmd, NULL, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
    std::cout << "parent2 " << std::endl;
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    system("pause");
}
```

result:
[image]

Another sample:

child

```
int main(VOID)
{
    //AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    int i = 5;
    while (i--)
    {
        printf("printf\n");
        std::cout << "child " << i << std::endl;
        fflush(stdout);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

parent

```
int main()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES se = {};
    se.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    se.bInheritHandle = true;
    se.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, &se, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    BOOL ret = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hFile);

    printf("parent1\n");
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    si.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    WCHAR cmd[] = L"Path\\child.exe";

    CreateProcessW(cmd, NULL, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
    
    std::cout << "parent2 " << std::endl;
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I saw no change with using `0` as the flag to `CreateProcess`,  as opposed to `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, but `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` did send child output to the parent screen. Strangely, opening a file and using `SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, h)` in the parent, where `h` is the handle to the file eliminated the output to the console window but the file remained empty. Very confusing.

Comment: `SetStdHandle` cannot affect the CRT handle of the current process (using by `printf()` `std::cout`...) see [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Console-Docs/issues/95), and but I can get the output of the child process in the following steps which calling `AttachConsole`. Do you open the file with write permission?

Comment: I've added the sample I am using. See the update.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. Working backwards I find that setting `bInheritHandles` to `TRUE` in `CreateProcess` breaks the behavior you demonstrate and sends stdout/stderr to someplace unknown. I have this flag set in order to pass a pipe handle to the child. I haven't found documentation explaining this behavior.

Comment: This is because the handle returned by `CreateFile` cannot be inherited by default. You need to specify the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter. And I found that it is also possible to directly redirect the stdout/stderr of the parent process to the child process without pipe, I've updated these two samples.

Comment: This is very strange, IMO. If I *don't* say to inherit handles in create process, the `STD_ERROR_HANDLE` and `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` (and the associated file handle) seem to be inherited in that writing to them in the child sent output to the file, but when I *did* say inherit handles, this behavior stopped, requiring an explicit request to inherit.

Further, what seems to require a specific request to inherit is the *file* handle, rather than the stderr/stdout handles. This wouldn't surprise me except for the behavior when `bInterhitHandles` was `false` in `CreateProcess`.

Comment: This is because when you say not inherit , the child process reacquires a new handle of parent console for output. Inheritance means that the same value can be used in the child process to represent this handle, instead of being unable to use this handle(when no inherit).